Can't Access internal storage after formatting SD card as internal then removing it
I integrated my SD card to use as phone memory. Everything was fine until a couple of days ago.
All of a sudden I saw the "insert SD card" notice appear on the notification bar. I open the back cover but the SD card looked like it was in place. I remove it and insert it back and then I formatted it as external then the notice disappears. But then I notice that when I go to file explorer (FX) to access my files, it doesn't show anything like the internal storage doesn't exist, crashes my settings when I click storage. I can't access anything that is on my phone memory, although the apps are working. I guess system files are okay.
My device is not rooted and it seems the only thing I can do now is to format my phone..I don't want to go that route please.

When you format an SD card as internal memory, then as the name says, its part of internal memory.
By removing it and reformatting, the phone is now missing internal memory.
You can try reformatting it as internal memory again. But if that doesn't work then you may have to factory reset your phone.
